# Remove directory, except when pointed to by symbolic link

Tags: bash, symlink, delete

I have the below directory structure. I need to find the directories in which a file called `log.xml` exists and remove all of them completely, except the directory which is pointed to by a specific symbolic link.

For example, `/dir1/main/app1/v004/` and `/dir1/main/app2/v004/log.xml` are pointed to by a symbolic link, so they should not be deleted.

Also how possible to remove the directory except pointed to by a symbolic link, without finding `log.xml`.

Could you please help with the correct solution for that?

```
/dir1/main/app1/v001/
/dir1/main/app1/v002/log.xml
/dir1/main/app1/v003/log.xml
/dir1/main/app1/v004/log.xml
/dir1/main/app1/v005/log.xml
/dir1/ln1/app -> /dir1/main/app2/v004

/dir1/main/app2/v001/
/dir1/main/app2/v002/log.xml
/dir1/main/app2/v003/log.xml
/dir1/main/app2/v004/log.xml
/dir1/main/app2/v005/log.xml
/dir1/ln2/app -> /dir1/main/app2/v004
```

Comment: So the result should be that `/dir1/main/app/v001` and `/dir1/main/app/v004` remain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to delete all the subdirectories of the `app` directory apart from `v001` (which does not contain `log.xml`) and `v004` (which is being pointed to by the symbolic link):

```bsh
for topdir in /dir1 /dir2; do

    for dirpath in "$topdir"/main/app/*/; do
            if [ -e "$dirpath/log.xml" ] && ! [ "$dirpath" -ef "$topdir"/ln/app ]
            then
                    printf 'Would remove "%s"\n' "$dirpath"
                    # rm -rf "$dirpath"
            fi
    done

done
```

The outer loop is used to loop over the two top-most directories `/dir1` and `/dir2` (you may possibly want to use `/dir[12]` as a globbing pattern there).  The name of the top-directory is kept in the `topdir` variable.

The inner loop iterates over the subdirectories beneath `app`, beneath `$topdir`.  If the subdirectory contains something called `log.xml` (the first test, with `-e`) and if the directory is not pointed to by the `"$topdir"/ln/app` symbolic link (the second test, with `-ef`), then it may be removed.

The `-e` test is a standard test for the existence of the given pathname.  The `-ef` test is non-standard but implemented by the `bash` shell, and it tests whether two pathnames refer to the same file (or directory in this case) after resolving symbolic links.

The actual removal is commented out for safety.  You should test this on data you have previously backed up before enabling the `rm` command.

To remove the subdirectories regardless of whether they contain something called `log.xml`, remove the `-e` test, so that the `if` statement looks like

```bsh
if ! [ "$dirpath" -ef "$topdir"/ln/app ]; then
        printf 'Would remove "%s"\n' "$dirpath"
        # rm -rf "$dirpath"
fi
```

Comment: @Emin If you have clarifications to your question, then please edit your question. It is difficult to read code and long list of pathnames in comments, and comments may be deleted at any time.

Comment: I have edited question. could you please review and help with correct way?

Comment: @Emin See updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much. Could you please also help in case with removing all dir except pointed to symlink without checking log.xml.

Comment: @Emin Just remove the `-e` test so that you have `if ! [ "$dirpath" -ef "$topdir"/ln/app ]; then ...`.

Comment: Thank you very much. its works fine.

Comment: One think. 
On some hosts not available these dir.
how it possible to skip it if dir not available?

Comment: @Emin Use `shopt -s nullglob` before the code that I present in my answer. That will cause the inner loop to be ignored if no names match the globbing pattern.

Comment: Great it works fine

Comment: @Emin, I'm noting that this, too, was not part of the actual question that you posed. Please don't continue asking further questions in the comments.

Comment: is it possible to use like below? >>>>>> 

for dirpath in /dir1/main/app/*/dir0/*;  

or like this  >>>>> 

for dirpath in /dir1/main/app/*_dir/*/

Thanks;

Answer (score 0):

GNU `find` has an option `-samefile`, you need to include -L option for this to work.

Take a look at the output of the following two commands

```
(cd /dir1 ; find -L . -samefile ln/app ) # your file and link

(cd /dir1 ; find -L . -not -samefile ln/app ) # everything other than your file and link
```

The second should produce a list of the files you wish to remove. Maybe you only want to list the files and not directories, if so then just add `-type f`

```
find -L . -type f -samefile ln/app)
```

removing the files is trivial, just append to the find command an exec action, eg `-exec rm -v {} \;`

Comment: This would probably remove all `log.xml` files (and whatever other files are stored in those directories), as they are not pointed to by the symbolic link.

Comment: Well yes, the question doesn't really specify what else is in those directories, I've provided a method to identify the linked files, and the inverse as a file list, which I thought was the essence of his question.

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestion.