# If permission denied then echo

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I use script from [Remove directory, except when pointed to by symbolic link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/689908/remove-directory-except-when-pointed-to-by-symbolic-link/690193#690193)

How can I check access and availability of directory before removing directory with script?
In some case dir may not available in one of the hosts. I need to check availability and access to dir before deletion.
I tried like that.

```
dirrm ()
{
for topdir in /dir1 /dir2; do

    for dirpath in "$topdir"/main/app/*/; do
            if [ -e "$dirpath/log.xml" ] && ! [ "$dirpath" -ef "$topdir"/ln/app ]
            then
                    printf 'Would remove "%s"\n' "$dirpath"
                    # rm -rf "$dirpath"
            fi
    done

done
}

if ! test /dir1/
   then
       printf 'No access to dir1\n'
   else 
       dirrm
fi
```

Thanks

Comment: either `test -w "$dir"` of `[ -w "$dir" ]`

Comment: If you are going to delete it, you will also need write permissions on the parent directory, although I assume you have them as you are running this as root.

Comment: Unfortunately it not works with test -w or test -d.

Comment: @Emin what doesn't work? What _exact_ command did you try? And _how_ did it fail?

Comment: Also, what's the point of testing? I mean, what better test than to just delete it: if it fails, then it wasn't available. What is the benefit of adding another step?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to expand the `"$topdir"/main/app/*/` glob, you need:

- search access to `$topdir/` (which you can check with `[ -x "$topdir/" ]`)
- search access to `"$topdir"/main/`.
- search and read access to `"$topdir"/main/app/`.
- for the files in `"$topdir"/main/app` that are symlinks, you'll also need search access to whatever directory must be traversed to reach the eventual target of the symlink.

To be able to check that `"$dirpath/log.xml` and `"$topdir"/ln/app` are two paths to the same file, you'll need search access to `"$topdir"/ln` and to the directories that must be traversed if those are symlinks.

To be able to do `rm -rf "$topdir"/main/app/some-subdir/`, first beware that if `some-subdir` is a symlink, that will empty the directory pointed to by the link, and may or may not delete the symlink itself or the directory it links to depending on the `rm` implementation.

In any case, you'll meed write access to `"$topdir"/main/app` and, unless `some-subdir` is empty , you'll also need search, read and write access to it (and to any non-empty subdirs, recursively). Also note the `t` bit could add complications.

Since you'll need read, write and search permission to `"$topdir"/main/app/`, just adding a:

```
dirrm ()
{
  for topdir in /dir1 /dir2; do
    appdir="$topdir/main/app/"
    if [ ! -w "$appdir" ] || [ ! -r "$appdir" ] || [ ! -x "$appdir" ]; then
      printf >&2 '%s\n' "I don't have the necessary access to $appdir"
      return 1
    fi
    ...
```

Would be a good start.